# How can I align text in a div to the center vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am having issues getting  this snippet of code aligned vertically and horizontally centered: `<h1 className="display-4 fw-bolder mb-4 text-center text-white">History</h1>`

any input helps. Thanks.

```
<div>
      <section id='vision'>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-8 mt-5">
              <h1 className="display-4 fw-bolder mb-4 text-center text-white">History</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
     
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by changing the `h1` to a `span` and add the following CSS style:

```
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
```

or by using the bootstrap classes on the span's parent:
`d-flex` `justify-content-center` `align-content-center`

```
<div>
      <section id='vision'>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-8 mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center">
              <span className="display-4 fw-bolder mb-4 text-center text-white">History</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
     
    </div>
```